# Algebraic manipulation in Rational Expressions and Factoring.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:
 4x/ (x^2 - 1) + 3x/ (1-x) - 4/(x-1)

4x/ (x+1)(x-1) -3x/(x-1) - 4/(x-1)

LCD: (x+1)(x-1)

4x/(x+1)(x-1) -3x(x+1)/(x+1)(x-1) -4(x+1)/(x+1)(x-1)

4x- 3x(x+1) - 4(x+1)/(x+1)(x-1)

So,Given the rational expression:

4x - 3x(x+1) - 4(x+1) / (x+1)(x-1)

why can you not remove (x+1) from the denominator and numerator?  Why is the following incorrect:

4x - 3x - 4 / (x-1)

Is the answer not:
4x-3x^2-3-4x-4/ (x+1)(x-1)

Which simplifies to:

-3x^2 -3x - 4/ (x+1)(x-1)

Perhaps related when simplifying something like

x^2 + 2x/x

is the x being divided from each term in the numerator? Is the answer x + 2? Or is it x + 2x, do you divide both terms or one by the denominator.

The highest math I have taken is Precalculus and I am now in college retaking Algebra 2 and discovering that I have some weak foundations in Algebraic manipulation like these problems. I have been very stressed recently since it is difficult to find out exactly which types of manipulations I am weak on. I only find out the things Im weak on when I get back a badly marked paper!

Answer (score 1):

Yes since $(x+1)$ appears on both terms, you can take that common, and then you have $\frac{x+1}{x+1} = 1$, but given that $x+1\neq 0$.

In general if you have an expression of the form
$\frac{AB+AC}{AD}$ you can rewrite it as $\frac{A(B+C)}{AD}$. Now if $A \neq 0$, you have that $\frac{A}{A} = 1$.

Comment: Why is it if I distribute in the problem above, I get a different solution than if I cancel out the (x+1)? I added the original problem to make things clearer. Basically I get -3x^2 -3x - 4/ (x+1)(x-1) when I distribute and x-4/x-1 when I remove the (x+1) in denominator and numerator!

Comment: @Sphygmomanometer Both rational expressions are exactly the same for $x +1 \neq 0$. You can try plotting both of them if you are having trouble. It basically means that for $x+1 \neq 0$, $\frac{x+1}{x+1} = 1$. Multiplying anything by $1$ does not change it ($1$ is multiplicative identity).

Comment: But if you plug in say 2 for both solutions you get different answers therefore they are not equal. x-4/x-1 != -3x^2-3x-4 / (x+1)(x-1) So what is the error?